# How to call route with value in view Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a datatable and I want to go to detail data page when I click the Data ID

```
<td><a href= "{{ route('ReservationDetail') }}" >{{ $getData->ID }}</a></td>
```

But I don't know how to add the ID inside the route in a view. In my controller I have a function like this below

```
return Redirect('ReservationDetail?ID='.$reservation->ID);
```

when I trying to make like that in my view, I always get error.

```
<td><a href= "{{ route("ReservationDetail?ID='.$getData->ID'") }}" >{{ $getData->ID }}</a></td>
```

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 307:
>   Route [ReservationDetail?ID='.3'] not defined

Comment: i would be better if you share your route file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your error is : `Route [ReservationDetail?ID='.3'] not defined` means it is failed to finding this route.

check `php artisan route:list`  in your terminal , and see is there any route exists with `ReservationDetail` name.

if not then try to add in your `web.php`

```
Route::get('/ReservationDetail',ReservationDetailController@get_by_id)->name('ReservationDetail');
```

try this in your `ReservationDetailController` :

```
function get_by_id($ID){
     $getData = ReservationDetail::where('ID',$ID)->first();
     return view('detail',compact('getData'));
}
```

in your blade view :

```
<a href= "{{ route('ReservationDetail', ['ID' => $getData->ID] ) }}">{{ $getData->ID }}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `url()` helper function.

```
<td><a href= "{{ url("ReservationDetail?ID='.$getData->ID'") }}" >{{ $getData->ID }}</a></td>
```